# Is C++ coroutine_handle invoking undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, gcc, coroutine

I was going through the coroutine_handle implementation from https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/coroutine#L251 and I stumbled across the fact that coroutine_handle have void* member variable to store the address.

Since we can convert from address to any promise type and vice versa using coroutine_handle API, doesn't it imply that type system is being abused here?

Was it not possible to implement the coroutine_handle using type safe methods?

**Edit**: Just to give some context.. I was writing an event loop and was passing task object around different threads, with task class being a template type. I introduced a bug (unintentionally) and I was basically able to convert one task type to another, which had different memory layout (due to specialization).

As per cppcon videos I saw on YouTube (which I am following for almost a year by now), the committee is trying to fill the holes of type system in C++ (I guess the title of video was 'type punning in C++'). I didn't expect that I will be able to do type punning using the feature of C++ that was introduced in C++20.

Comment: `void*` is absence, not abuse of type system. Why do you think there would be undefined behavior?

Comment: Even if it were, an implementation of C++ can coordinate with itself to ensure that it's use of behaviours undefined by the standard only ever result in correct behaviour.

Comment: The standard library can use things that are formally undefined by simply defining them for a specific compiler. Some things are specifically put into the library because mere mortals cannot write an `offsetof` macro, for example.

Comment: Hi, I updated my post to give more context. Regarding `void*` being the absence of type system, I was relying on library implementation to not let me perform type punning, so that I can focus on making my event loop. Compiler not being able to identify this in code is the source of errors

Comment: And as per my interpretation, type punning is undefined behaviour. (Not sure, but feels like it). And standard library is supposed to (I guess) use best C++ practices and not rely on tricks that bypasses the language best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the standard library cannot invoke undefined behavior any more than the compiler can invoke undefined behavior. They form the implementation of the language together. A user of the standard library may invoke undefined behavior by violating the rules of the implementation.

Second, storing `void*` is a form of type erasure. It is often helpful to pass objects through layers of code or store them in containers, without everything becoming a template. The standard library has a few type-erased types, including `std::function<Sig>` and `std::any`.

Type erasure is not type punning. When the library provides the ability to restore the type, the user must supply the correct type. One is not allowed to read a type as another type.

The main difference is `std::coroutine_handle::from_address` enforces that with a precondition (and UB on violation) while `std::any_cast` checks the condition. While UB is falling out of favor, preconditions and UB continue to appear in new non-trivial C++ types and that is unlikely to change.

Comment: Hey, I think I get the idea here. But the second part of my question is still unsolved. (Was it not possible to implement the coroutine_handle using type safe solutions?)

Comment: But there are non-erased specializations. If you don't need the erased one, you don't have to use it. On the other hand, it provides value (ABI, virtual function arguments, usual erasure benefits) and it does not require many of the usual tradeoffs (erasure usually requires heap allocation, but the coroutine design requires that already).

Comment: I am assuming that you are referring to non erased specializations of coroutine handle. Can you please refer some? I went over gcc and clang implementation (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__coroutine/coroutine_handle.h#L187) and both use type erased implementation

Comment: The specializations with a non-void promise type is here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__coroutine/coroutine_handle.h#L106C26-L106C26